# Load custom UIView xib programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3, xib, iboutlet

I'm trying to load a custom UIView into a view controller from code in Swift as I used to do in Objective-C, but I'm facing a lot of trouble.
I tried some solutions I saw here, but my IBOutlets are not initialized and I get unwrapping crashes because of that.
All in all I can't find a way to do it, the code I used until now is this:

```
 - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTitle:(NSString *)title andInfo:(NSString *)info {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomAlertView" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[DICustomAlertView class]])
        {
            self = (DICustomAlertView *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (self) {
        self.frame = frame;
        self.lblTitle.text = title;
        self.lblInfo.text = info;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And to load the view I just called:

```
DICustomAlertView *cav = [[DICustomAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andTitle:@"Title" andInfo:@"Info"];
[self.view addSubview:cav];
```

I can't find a way to "translate" it into Swift since all the "self" management goes different, does anyone know about a solution equivalent to this one?

Comment: Yeah that's the nice theory. Taking it into practice it's the problem, i didn't try to translate it but I couldn't get to a solution in any other way.

Comment: Do step by step. :) First Google something like "initWithFrame uiview swift". Then search for how to loop over the result of the equivalent of loadNibNamed in Swift. Then look at the equivalent of isKindOfClass (which is just `is`) - and of course, check that you *do* need to do that in Swift. Apple has very complete documentation about UIView and its inits. Etc.